# Highcharts: Is it possible to style individual pie chart slices?

Tags: css, highcharts

I would like to style Highcharts individual pie chart slices using css. Highcharts has a way of setting different colours on the pie chart slices but I cannot find an easy way to set these colours through css.

Most of the other questions on SO that come up when doing similar searches relate to styling the labels, not the actual svg paths themselves.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Highcharts doesn't provide such option. At least, not right now, see info about [Highcharts 5.0](http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap) ;)

Answer (score 1):

***Via CSS*** use

```
path:nth-of-type(2){
      fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

> For other pie colors the 2 to rest of the values.

***Via JS*** use

```
colors : ['#4572A7', '#AA4643', '#89A54E', '#80699B', '#3D96AE', 
   '#DB843D', '#92A8CD', '#A47D7C', '#B5CA92'],
```

> Inside highcharts initialization as a json obeject.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eb3fx88w/8/)

Comment: Any way to programatically set a css class to individual slices, I need to do this in a dynamic fashion. I won't know till runtime what slices are displayed.

Comment: @AranMulholland as far as i can inderstand u want an external class to be added to each slices but that time too how will u identify this slice to this class. the above code can be set via nth-of-type(0,,,,,8) so that what ever slices you get u can change the default color to your customised wish,

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself, so this is a very late answer, but may be helpful for anyone else who finds themselves here.

In the current version of Highcharts, using the "styled" option, the default Highcharts stylesheet creates a series of 10 selectors like this, numbered 0-9:

```
.highcharts-color-0 {
  fill: #7cb5ec;
  stroke: #7cb5ec;
}
```

You can see them in the highcharts.css available via CDN: https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css

So in your stylesheet you can override these colors with your own, after loading the highcharts.css file.

The colors are also applied to the legend labels.

**Update:** [Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/toppa/q3ufjs7y/3/) - I set the first 3 pie slice colors to red, blue, and green (I copied most of the example from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/styled-mode-pie/) and then added the colors).

Comment: Thanks. I tried editing their demo sites in the chrome inspector and adding this to to the element, an inline script to the head and a style tag was unable to get the style to apply, you got an example we could see where it does get applied? In fact even when I go through the document and edit the style tags and make them all .highcharts-color-0 it still does not change colour.

Comment: [Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/toppa/q3ufjs7y/1/) - I set the first 3 pie slice colors to red, blue, and green (I copied most of the example from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/styled-mode-pie/) and then added the colors).

I'm not an expert on the inner workings of Highcharts, but you said you made edits using the Chrome inspector, so that makes me think there may be an issue with trying to modify the css after the chart has rendered.